# jQuery updating ancestor content when nested element is removed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using jQuery 3.6

I am deleting a nested element from a portion of my page, and I want that section of the page to automatically update, to reflect the change - I was expecting the browser to automatically update the modified section, but it doesn't and the change is only visible when I refresh the page.

#### Here is a snippet of the HTML:

```
 <div id="foo" class="row text-center text-lg-left">

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a id="abc-1"><img src="image1"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
      <a id="abc-2"><img src="image2"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- etc -->

</div>
```

#### Here is my Javascript snippet:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "/path/to/post/to",
                data: {'identifier': $(this).attr('id'), 'status':1, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '1234567abc'},,
                success: function(data) {
                   /* assume we have variable named 'identifier' ... */
                   $(`a#${identifier}`).parent().remove();
                   
                   /* next two lines is a brute-force attempt to
                      force the element to update - but it still
                      doesn't update, until I refresh the page!
                   */
                   let remaining_content = $('div#foo').html()
                   $('div#foo').html(remaining_content);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                  var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                  alert(status);
                  alert(error);
                  alert(err.Message);
                }    
});
```

How do I get the div with id `foo` to update (ideally with some nice color fade-in/out) when it's content changes (deletion of elements in this case) - without having to refresh the browser to observe the change?

Comment: Please add sample data and explain what outcome you expect. And yes it should update. Thats what Jquery is for, manipulating the DOM

Comment: Read this several times and finding it hard to figure out exactly what you are asking or expecting here. *"automatically update, to reflect the change"* ..update in what way and with what change?

Comment: @charlietfl I have a list of items (represented by a list of **divs** with *nested* **anchor** s. When I programatically delete one of the items in the list (i.e. a div), I want the browser to show that an item in the list has been removed. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the element that was clicked on with `$(this)` - also you can show the update using css and appling a `changed` class

```js
$('[data-rel=remove]').click(function() {
        /*$.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: "/path/to/post/to",
          data: {
            'identifier': $(this).attr('id'),
            'status': 1,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '1234567abc'
          },
          success: function(data) {
            // assume we have variable named 'identifier' ...  
            
            */
        $(this).parent().remove();
        onChanged('div#foo');
        /*
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    alert(status);
    alert(error);
    alert(err.Message);
  }
});
*/
})
        const onChanged = (el) => {
          $(el).addClass('changed')
          setTimeout(() => $(el).removeClass('changed'), 500)
        }
```

```css
div {
  padding: 15px;
  transition: background-color .5s, border .5s;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

div.changed {
  background-color: #FEFFAA;
  border: 1px dashed yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo" class="row text-center text-lg-left">

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
    <a data-rel='remove' id="abc-1">Click to remove </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
    <a data-rel='remove' id="abc-2">Click to remove</a>
  </div>

  <!-- etc -->

</div>
```

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my question. I have a list of items displayed on a page, and I want to delete items programatically from the list - and have the page 'update' / refresh itself when an item is deleted.

Comment: yes, thanks! That's exactly what I'm trying to achieve. Gimme a little while to grok your answer (I'm not very familiar with arrow functions).

Comment: dont' let those trip you up. They're just like regular functions as far as this example goes. `setTimeout(() => $(el).removeClass('changed'), 500)` is the same as `setTimeout(function(){ $(el).removeClass('changed')}, 500)`